# Why is there only one Giant in the series

Tags: game-of-thrones

It might be a spoiler if anyone has not completed the season 5-6 of *[Game of Thrones](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/)* yet.

My question is about why they only showed a single giant in the series and not more. Is there only this one or only this one involved in the fights or was there some other reason?

Comment: Wrong premises, there were more , did you forgot [Mag Mar Tun Doh Weg](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mag_Mar_Tun_Doh_Weg) and [Dongo](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dongo). I think you mixed all of them into Wun Wun

Comment: So they are all 3, it means

Comment: There is one unnamed one according to [wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Giants) but i don't remember if it's even mentioned in the show or not.

Comment: For a none-lore reason, CGI budget. They couldn't afford to CGI in both the giant and Ghost for the Battle of the Bastards.

Comment: Related SFF question: [In the GoT book and/or HBO canon, are the giants now below a minimum viable population?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/94016/21267)

Comment: @SGR That's also the same reason why we had a giant in "Battle of the Bastards", but no Ghost.  The showrunners basically had to pick which CGI character they were going to have onscreen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are few reasons why there are so few giants shown on-screen. (There's more than one -- at least three, but still not many):

- Giants don't like people. Ygritte calls them "shy", but it seems more that they avoid human contact. The fact that Mance managed to get any of them at all to come help him was a pretty big deal.
- They're nearly extinct. I don't know if there was anything specifically mentioned in the show, but in the novels the total population of Giants is in the low hundreds at most. So seeing one at all is *very* rare. (Some smart people in the show do claim to believe the giants are extinct, but they said the same thing about dragons and Children of the Forest, so...)

Of the three giants Mance recruited, two of them died in the assault on Castle Black, so the one that you keep seeing everywhere is just the only one left alive after the wildlings move through the Wall.

Comment: I think Mance says to Jon after the battle that one of the killed giants was the last of his line. It's definitely strongly implied that there are few.